# php session stuck on filtered results

Tags: php, session

**index.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['type']=$_GET['type'];
}
<a href="index.php?type=makeup"><button>Makeup Artists</button></a>
<a href="index.php?type=photography"><button>photography</button></a>
```

**fetch.php**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['type'])){
  $typesql = $_SESSION['type'];
  $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, type FROM artists WHERE type = ?");

  $results->bind_param("s", $typesql);
  $results->execute();
  $results->bind_result($name, $type);
} else {
  $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, type FROM artists");

  $results->execute();
  $results->bind_result($name, $type);
}
```

after starting the session when I return to index.php with no $_GET values I still get the filtered results, I tried the below solution but it didn't work

```
if (isset($_GET['session'])) {
if($_GET['session']==0){
  session_unset();
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the session value and use `empty()` instead of `isset()` on the fetch page:

**/index.php**

```
# Just start by default
session_start();
# Set default
$_SESSION['type'] = (isset($_GET['type']))? $_GET['type'] : false;
?>
<a href="index.php?type=makeup"><button>Makeup Artists</button></a>
<a href="index.php?type=photography"><button>photography</button></a>
```

**/fetch.php**

```
# Use empty() here
if(!empty($_SESSION['type'])){
    $typesql = $_SESSION['type'];
    $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, type FROM artists WHERE type = ?");

    $results->bind_param("s", $typesql);
    $results->execute();
    $results->bind_result($name, $type);
} else {
    $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, type FROM artists");
    $results->execute();
    $results->bind_result($name, $type);
}
```

Comment: from what I've understood I only changed isset to empty in the fetch page, however the result is the same

Comment: No, you have to have what I have on the index as well. Without that the fetch will have no effect

Comment: now it works, thanks!!, can you please explain what I was doing wrong?

Comment: If I have answered the question, please mark as answered so others know it's solved. What you didn't do is reset the session value (in this case I made it empty if GET not set)